# Use strong induction to prove piecewise function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$H_0 = 0, H_1 = 1, H_2 = 1$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ where $n \geq 3$:

Prove for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$
H_n = H_{n−1} + H_{n−2} − H_{n−3}.
$$
$$
H_n =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{n}{2},  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\[2ex]
\dfrac{n+1}{2}, & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$

I don't know how the inductive step $k+1$ in a strong induction would go for piecewise function like this. I think I'll have to show the proposition hold when $k+1$ is even and odd, but I don't know how to continue the proof.

Comment: The post says "where $n\ge3$" but doesn't go on to say how $H_n$ is defined then.

Comment: I've added it in! sorry to have missed this part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just do both cases and see if each of them is correct. Since this case distinction was exhaustive, the statement is correct. I'll present the inductive step:

Suppose the explicit form of $H_n$ holds for $k-3, k-2, k-1$. Now we only have two possible cases:

1. $k$ is even. Note that $k-2$ is also even, but $k-1$ and $k-3$ are odd. We have
   $$
      H_k = H_{k-1} + H_{k-2} - H_{k-3} = \frac{(k-1)+1}{2} + \frac{k-2}{2} - \frac{(k-3)+1}{2} = \frac{k}{2},
      $$
   which satisfies the given expression for $H_n$.
2. $k$ is odd. Note that $k-2$ is also odd, but $k-1$ and $k-3$ are even. We have
   $$
      H_k = H_{k-1} + H_{k-2} - H_{k-3} = \frac{k-1}{2} + \frac{(k-2)+1}{2} - \frac{k-3}{2} = \frac{k+1}{2},
      $$
   which also satisfies the given expression for $H_n$.

In conclusion, the above expression for $H_n$ is correct in every possible case, so it is true in general. QED